# Angular 12 Error: ... from Css Minimizer, Transform failer with 1 error, Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

While running `ng build --configuration=production` I get the following error.

```
Error: C:/.../.scss from Css Minimizer
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
```

How can I if fix this?

Comment: I have just found this issue after I update my project from Angular 11 to 12 and run it with the comman `ng serve`. Could somebody help us?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been fixed in version `12.2.16` and `13.2.1` of `@angular/cli`.

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606

Answer (score 12):

#### Temporary fix

*This is not really the solution, but a temporary fix*
I had to add the following into my `.browserslistrc` file.

```
not ios_saf 15.2-15.3
not safari 15.2-15.3
```

Doing so will fix the error.

#### Solution

As @HeroWanders mentioned in his answer, this did get fix in the [v12.2.16](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606) of the [@angular/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) library

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, what worked for me was also updating `ng-packagr` to `12.2.7`. As far as I know, that's the only way to fix this without updating to Angular 13 (which I can't, because of an unlucky dependency).

see [this comment on github](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8768#issuecomment-1050710663) or [my SO post about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949507/angular-12-error-from-css-minimizer-error-transform-failed-with-1-error-er)