# Angular 12 Error ... from Css Minimizer Error: Transform failed with 1 error: error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"

Tags: angular, markdown, angular12, javascript-marked

I know this question has been asked before, but I seem to have a slightly different problem (at least, the solution provided in similar questions don't work for me).

**The project is using Angular 12,  there is (sadly) a required dependency that has not yet been able to update to Angular 13.**

After updating the library `ngx-markdown` to v12.1.0, I had the error that `node_modules/marked/lib/marked.js does not exist`, so I changed the path in the `angular.json` script, as suggested on [github](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown/issues/377).

Then, I got this error:

```
Error: Transform failed with 1 error: 
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925649/angular-12-error-from-css-minimizer-transform-failer-with-1-error-invalid), I updated `@angular/cli` to 12.2.16, but this did not solve the issue for me.

Next, I tried to delete the `node_modules` file, and the `package-lock.json` and reinstalled everything, this also did not work.

Then, I tried to delete the `.browserslistrc` file, and also adding to it `ios_saf 15.2-15.3`, both as suggested on [this github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606), but neither worked.

Does anyone have an idea what I could try next? Otherwise I guess the best solution would be to revert to `ngx-markdown` v12.0.0 despite the vulnerability..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the error following these steps:

1. Update script in angular.json `"node_modules/marked/marked.min.js",`
2. Update angular/angular-devkit versions like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "12.2.0",
// …
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.16",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.16",
// …
}
```

3. Update `ng-packagr` to "12.2.7"

Now it compiles without any issues. I also didn't need any changes to the browserlistrc file, which is the commonly suggested solution for the error.

-> In case someone is wondering, my browserlistrc file looks like this:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

Kudos to github user [fischeversenker](https://github.com/fischeversenker) for this comment: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8768#issuecomment-1050710663